# Need the Syntax for a SQL 'like' Query through VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am using MS SQL and trying to run a query using vb.net
I want to get data like 
101
102
...
110
111
...

The Query I executed in MS SQL is

```
select Book_Code, Book_Name from famsetup where book_code like '1%'
```

and this runs fine and gives me proper result...

When I write following code in vb.net written below,

```
ListViewBound(LstViewHelp, "Select Book_Code, Book_Name from FAMSETUP where Book_Code like '1%'", con1)
```

I don't get any value...

Note:- Listviewbound is my function and properly working on other places in my program, I just showed this full line...

Is my query wrong writing in vb.net???

What query should I write in vb.net???

Any help accepted...! :/

The other codes are

Listviewbound

```
Sub ListViewBound(lvw As ListView, QRY As String, Xcn As SqlConnection)
    Try
        cmd = New SqlCommand(QRY, Xcn)
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        dt = New DataTable
        Dim ListView1 As ListView = New ListView
        da.Fill(dt)
        lvw.View = View.Details
        lvw.GridLines = True
        lvw.Columns.Clear()
        lvw.Items.Clear()
        For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            lvw.Columns.Add(col.ToString)
        Next
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim lst As ListViewItem
            lst = lvw.Items.Add(If(row(0) IsNot Nothing, row(0).ToString, ""))
            For i As Integer = 1 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                lst.SubItems.Add(If(row(i) IsNot Nothing, row(i).ToString, ""))
            Next
        Next
        For i = 0 To lvw.Items.Count - 1
            If i Mod 2 Then
                lvw.Items(i).BackColor = Color.White
            Else
                lvw.Items(i).BackColor = Color.LightBlue
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The Connection string Code

```
    Sub CompDb_Open()
    Try
        con1.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=bonny;Integrated Security=True"
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: I also tried 1 %, 1_%

Comment: We need to see the actual connection to the database and querying code.

Comment: Oh god, its too deep....
Okie wait, I try to get it and give you..... @AllanS.Hansen

Comment: Do you anywhere open your connection and I dont see it?

Comment: The code is going from one place to other so it'll be alot deep..

I just gave you required code... Plz try to understand....If I gave all the stuff the question will be big which may get against the rules of Stackoverflow.... @AllanS.Hansen

Comment: Yes I opened the connection, my code is tricky, I have to post other private subs also, brother, there is no problem in connections, all working fine... I just dont know the query.....@apomene

Comment: If you exclude the where part of your query - does it return stuff?

Comment: Plz guyz, don't bother with connections, its all goooood..... :)

Comment: Wait, I check....@AllanS.Hansen

Comment: @RitaShroff The query is ok. Have in mind that there should be no change in your query because you are running it through a vb program. The problem lies elsewhere

Comment: yes if I remove where part, it returns but it returns everything @AllanS.Hansen

Comment: Ya I tried keeping the query same, the query gives proper result in mssql and no result here in vb.net, as said by Allan above, removing where also gives me data in vb.net but I don't need all that data...@apomene

Comment: Well - if the query works correctly in the database, and the query works without the where part in your code, then something has to manipulate the query's where part in the code. Try the query in native SqlClient code - not using all the wrapper layers/functions you use. Make a simple connection, use the command, execute datareader, check result .... basically - debug it :)

Comment: Okie, I'll try as you said and inform you... Long work but will do anything for result @AllanS.Hansen

Comment: You need to put a breakpoint and figure out exactly what is happening. You haven't told where in your code you have the problem. Is the DT empty? Are the lvw.Columns not being added? Are the lst not being added? Did you write all that code before debugging? If yes, you would write one or two lines and test them than write a few more lines.

Comment: @RitaShroff It should take no more than few minutes to check if the query is returning data via debugging; it's not much work to write those 4-6 lines.

Comment: Okie, got data through data reader as said by Allan, now placing that thing in my code will be a big deal for me...... Thanx anyways... But I am confused that all other queries working in my existing code and not this... Strange...!!! @AllanS.Hansen

Comment: Is BookCode a string in SQL Server or a number?

Comment: varchar(9) -> string @rheitzman